# What will happen when our set calendar ends?

Tags: calendar, chagim-holidays, latid-lavo-future

In a recent conversation I was told that the current Jewish calendar was only set till the year 6,000.  There was conjecture as to what will happen after that time (assuming Moshiach has not yet arrived). The general consensus was that there will no longer be any Jewish holidays. I would like to know if this is correct. If not please provide an explanation as to what **will** happen when the calendar runs out.

Comment: Do you have a Source? The calendar will be working fine then (though sightly later).

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14509/why-does-the-jewish-calendar-have-to-end/14511#14511 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23060/an-improved-jewish-calendar-after-this-one-expires http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15889/destruction-of-the-world-after-1000-years-of-moshiach

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23060? Ping @Menachem.

Comment: @msh210: they all overlap

Comment: Purim won’t be abolished. Just the others.

Comment: Is Keitz Hayamim the year 6,000, or whenever Moshiach shows up? I assume if by 6,000 Moshiach hasn't come yet chv''sh, we will continue as normal until he does.

Comment: Nothing. Absolutely nothing. Jokes aside, the messiah will/should come.

Comment: Maybe a new calendar will take its place? Or not.

Answer (score 1):

You stated:

> The general consensus was that there will no longer be any Jewish holidays.
>   I would like to know if this correct.

I don't know who you polled, but that is **incorrect**. One of the 13 principles of our faith is that the Torah is eternal.

> If not please provide an explanation as to what will happen when the calendar runs out.

Firstly the general consensus is that Moshiach will have arrived before the year 6,000, so there should be nothing to do.

If not, then the Rabbis will have to convene and agree on how to readjust the calculations, or (even better, but less likely) decide to start using witnesses, as in the olden days, after agreeing to reinstate the Sanhedrin.

Comment: "the Torah is eternal" That doesn't mean the holidays have to happen. If we don't Mekadesh the Chodesh, maybe the holiday doesn't happen that year (recall it's "mekadesh YISRAEL vehazemannim"). The Ritva  (Chullin 101a) actually implies this. The 13 principles of faith have nothing to do with this at all.

Comment: @DoubleAA I still think it's slightly out of context to make the assumption that there will no longer be Jewish holidays.

Comment: The Tora says כל מלאכת עבודה לא תעשו and it is eternal following the 13 principles of faith