# Can you have a new year w/o a halachic Rosh Hashana?

Tags: calendar, rosh-hashanah-new-year

Rabbi Breitowitz raised this point (listen for approx 2-3 min from [here](https://youtu.be/4R38iZfSkA8?t=20m24s), the point starts at 22:30m) Since the Jewish calendar was not sanctified (with a Rosh Hashana) beyond the year 5999, is it even possible to move into the year 6000 without a duly constituted Sanhedrin declaring appointed times? In other words, if Moschiach doesn't come by the year 6000, are we stuck in the year 5999 because we have no way of moving halachically into the year 6000?

Edit 2: As @DoubleAA states [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31372/what-will-happen-when-our-set-calendar-ends?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment242130_79818)

> That doesn't mean the holidays have to happen. If we don't Mekadesh
>   the Chodesh, maybe the holiday doesn't happen that year (recall it's
>   "mekadesh YISRAEL vehazemannim"). The Ritva (Chullin 101a) actually
>   implies this.

Edit 1: The question above is crisply stated and embedded in this [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91858/what-is-the-source-for-hillel-s-having-included-an-expiration-date-in-the-calend)

Comment: "Since the Jewish calendar was not sanctified (with a Rosh Hashana) beyond the year 5999" explaining this line and including some sources, would definitely improve the quality of this question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77105/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-bilar-can-you-have-a-new-year-w-o-a-halachic-ro).

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not sure that they're duplicates. That question asks whether or not we will have chagim after 5999. This question takes as a given that we will not have chagim, and then asks whether the absence of Rosh HaShanah means the year count stays stuck on 5999 (although I'm not sure what the significance of that would be...)