# Mishna Berura's Time for Mashiach

Tags: messiah, mishnah-berurah

[Rav Moshe Heinemann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Heinemann) mentioned during a shiur that the Mishna Berura in  קידוש החודש writes Mashiach will come before 5743. Unfortunately, I am having difficulty locating it precisely - where is this Mishna Berura located?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is probably based on what the Mishnah Berurah writes in the Beiur Halacha in [siman 427](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40448&st=&pgnum=186), but I don't think it is entirely accurate.

The discussion there is about calculating the molad for future years. The Beiur Halacha mentions that up until the year 5847 the listings in the calendar of the Tur are accurate, and we don't have to worry about beyond that because the Redemption will have come by then, and even well before then (see bold below).

The year 5743 is only mentioned in a parenthetical, as one of the years which has a printer's error in it.

> כשראש חודש וכו'. ועיין סדר הקביעות בטור והנה בטור סידר הקביעות שכל י"ג
>   מחזורים קביעותם שוה והוא מה שקראו הלבוש עיגול דרב נחשון גאון אך הלבוש
>   כתב ע"ז המון המעברים חושבים י"ג מחזורים בשוה אבל כשתדקדק היטב תמצא
>   שאינו כן עכ"ל וכן העתיק בהגהת ב"א מספר יסוד עולם מאמר רביעי פרק יו"ד
>   בסופו כי מה שסוברים שכל הי"ג מחזורים הם בשוה הוא רק ברוב השנים אבל לא
>   בכולם ולכן אין לסמוך על עיגול זה של י"ג מחזורות עכ"ל ע"ש באריכות וכן
>   בפר"ח השיג על הטור ופירש השנים האיך עולה לפי חשבון וכמ"ש בספר תקון
>   יששכר והזהיר מאוד מאוד שלא לשמוע לסדר הקביעות של הטור על שנים ידועות
>   ע"ש וכן מצאתי עוד בשאר ספרים אך לעניננו אין שום נ"מ מזה כי על שנים
>   שעברו עד הנה מה דהוה הוה וגם באמת כבר נתקן באיזה מקומות בלוח של הטור
>   גופא כפי מה שהגיה הפר"ח ועל שנת תרס"ב תרס"ג תש"ז תש"ח כתבתי לקמן איך
>   הוא הקביעות באמת עי"ש ויתר השנים משך רב כמעט עד שנת תתמ"ז כתובות בלוח
>   הטור כהוגן כפי מה שנראה מפר"ח שלא הגיה עליו [אם לא שימצא עוד איזה
>   קלקול בדפוס וכמו שראיתי בפר"ח כתוב שם על שנת תתקנ"ג סימן בח"ג והוא
>   טה"ד וצ"ל זח"ג וכן על שנת תשמ"ג כתוב בדפוס לעמבערג בש"ז והוא טה"ד וצ"ל
>   ז"ש כמו בטור והוא זש"ג אח"כ מצאתי כן בדפוס ישן] **ואין לנו לדאוג כ"כ
>   יותר כי בודאי בעת ההיא וגם הרבה קודם יהיה הגאולה ונקדש ע"פ הראיה**

Comment: “Up until the year 5847 the listings in the calendar of the Tur are accurate.” But after that year they’re not accurate? What suddenly changes?

Comment: @doniel this happens https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/64085/759 Basically 247 is an approximation and the error adds up to a day in 5847

Comment: At any rate ,it is very common to talk in such terms, such as "the Messiah will surely be here by then"

Comment: Completely random, but if you add the "missing 160 years", that comes remarkably close to 6000.   ;)